# Some people are just passer-byes

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

I was wondering if someone could tell me if the bold word below in my self-made sentence works or not? If it doesn't sound natural, then please let me know what shall I use instead:

> Most of the people are **passer-byes** in your life. People come and go. But there are a few people who you can never forget them.

P.S. I think the sentence is expressive alone, but please let me know if I have to explain more.

Comment: Most of the people in your life are just passersby.

Comment: The compound "passer-by" is formed of  a noun+preposition, so it follows that the plural is formed by adding .s to the noun to give "passers-by". It's the same as "runners-up" and "hangers-on". Note the hyphens in all those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is a great tool, and it's smart too. Have you ever noticed that whenever you make a spelling mistake it tries to correct you, and suggest valid alternatives?

Just by typing **passer**, Google provided a few suggestions. When I typed the OP's expression in bold ***passer byes*** Google opened the page with

> [image]

---

So to answer the OP's question, first check the spelling. The singular form is written **passerby**, but (and this is the interesting part) the suffix **-s** must be attached to *passer* and not to the preposition *by*. Therefore, the plural form is *passer**s**by*, NOT *passerbys*.

I would re-write the OP's sentence as

> The majority of people in **our lives** are *just* passersby.
>   Most of the people **in life** / **in your life** are just passersby.

OR

> The majority of people in your life are just **passing by**.

The phrasal verb, to **pass by**  means *to go past*

> “She would beg from the people passing by”

Comment: It's a great pity the OP didn't do a preliminary research, if they had, and found the answer their next step might have been to ask: "why" the suffix -s is not attached immediately at the end of the noun. A missed opportunity.

Comment: You're right @Mari-Lou A. I'll try more from now on. :)